# Monterey: Show two Spaces side by side on one physical monitor

Tags: display, spaces

I frequently share my desktop on Zoom (and similar tools).  I might be tiling or swapping between a few Chrome windows, a PDF viewer, an SSH session, etc.

I sometimes use a big wide monitor that gets compressed unhelpfully when I share with people on more-standard-proportion monitors. Even if I'm on a more standard monitor, I have certain windows and apps that I might not want to share, such as a chat app or email, or Chrome windows where I preview stuff before sharing it, or look up supporting information.

I can throw certain apps or windows into a different Space, but then I can't view them without toggling, and I'm not sure this would preserve the privacy of my applications.  This is awkward.

What I'd really like to do is have two Spaces side by side on my monitor -- effectively, split my physical monitor into two virtual monitors. Is there a way to do this natively with Spaces?  If not, what are the preferred third-party apps in 2024 to accomplish this?

Comment: Doesn‘t Zoom support sharing of windows instead of the whole desktop?